# How do I retrive a JSON object then store into a regular javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, xmlhttprequest

I have this on link in json format, I have to retrive it

```
    {"vehicles":[{"name":"motorcycle","wheels":2,"maxCapacity":2,"currentPassengers":1,"maxSpeed":"260 km/h"},{"name":"car","wheels":4,"maxCapacity":4,"currentPassengers":3,"maxSpeed":"220 km/h"},{"name":"aeroplane","wheels":18,"maxCapacity":416,"currentPassengers":215,"maxSpeed":"920 km/h"}]}
```

to store it into a regular javascript object.

Comment: See `JSON.parse()`

Comment: That is also a javascript object. You can store it right away.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = JSON.parse({"vehicles":[{"name":"motorcycle","wheels":2,"maxCapacity":2,"currentPassengers":1,"maxSpeed":"260 km/h"},{"name":"car","wheels":4,"maxCapacity":4,"currentPassengers":3,"maxSpeed":"220 km/h"},{"name":"aeroplane","wheels":18,"maxCapacity":416,"currentPassengers":215,"maxSpeed":"920 km/h"}]})
```

then you can use as `obj.vehicles` in order to access vehicles.